# How to set the binding text on code behind

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created the userControl in which has two textblock. I can set the text on xaml page for using this code.

```
    <my:Title Title  TitleCaption="test On XMAL"   />
```

However  I want to set the value of the text on the code. Would someone show me how to achieve this task? Thanks in advance.

There is my userControl:

```
<UserControl x:Name="TitleSection"  x:Class="CMSPhoneApp.Title"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource GridTitleStyle1}" >

    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="ApplictionTtile" Width="350" Text="MyAppTitle " HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock   x:Name="PageTtile"  Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
               Text="{Binding Path=TitleCaption, Mode=TwoWay,  ElementName=TitleSection }"      
                     >


         </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The following is code behind of this page:

```
namespace CMSPhoneApp
{
    public partial class Title : UserControl
    {
    public Title()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty TitleCaptionProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("TitleCaption", typeof(string), typeof(Title), null);

    public string TitleCaption
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleCaptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleCaptionProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a much easier way, your property should be:

```
public string TitleCaption
    {
        get
        {
            return PageTitle.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            PageTitle.Text=value;
        }
    }
```

Now when you create the control name it:

```
<my:Title Name="myTitle"  TitleCaption="test On XMAL"   />
```

Now you can change PageTitle from code by the following code:

```
myTitle.TitleCaption="your Text Goes Here";
```

Comment: You should upvote and mark the answer that helped you the most as best. This helps your helper in gaining reputation :). You're welcome by the way....

Answer (score 0):

From the code you can do something like :

```
PageTtile.Text = "This is from code"; // where PageTile is the x:Name of the TextBlock in XAML
```